How do you create real-time audio transcription using PyAudio, Silero VAD, and WhisperX?
I have been trying to get real-time audio transcription to work, but I am not sure what I'm doing.
What I am trying to achieve:

Continuously record audio using PyAudio and checking to see if audio chunks have speech using Silero VAD.
Audio chunks that contain speech will be appended to list until VAD detects audio chunk with no speech.
List of audio chunks with speech will be concatenated as numpy array and send to WhisperX for transcription.
Repeat process until keyboard interrupted.

This is my attempt at coding:
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
model = load_silero_vad()
vad_iterator = VADIterator(model)


whisper_model = whisperx.load_model("base", device=device, compute_type="float32", language='en')

# initialize pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Define audio stream parameters
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16-bit format
CHANNELS = 1              # Mono audio
RATE = 16000              # Sampling rate (Hz)
CHUNK = 512              # Buffer size

# Open audio stream
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)


speech_buffer = []

SILENCE_THRESHOLD = 80  # Number of consecutive non-speech frames to tolerate
silence_count = 0  # Counter for consecutive non-speech frames

try:
    while True:
        # Read audio data from the stream
        audio_data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        # Convert audio data to numpy array and normalize to float32
        audio_np = np.frombuffer(audio_data, dtype=np.int16).astype(np.float32) / 32768.0

        # Apply VAD to detect speech
        speech_dict = vad_iterator(audio_np, RATE)

        if speech_dict:
            silence_count = 0
            # Speech detected
            print("Speech detected!")
            speech_buffer.append(audio_np)
        else: # no speech
            silence_count += 1
            print("Speech not detected.")
            print(silence_count)
            print("length of speech buffer: ", len(speech_buffer))

            # Process audio if silence count exceeds threshold and there's buffered audio
            if silence_count > SILENCE_THRESHOLD and speech_buffer:
                print("Processing audio.")
                speech_audio = np.concatenate(speech_buffer)

                print(speech_audio)
               
                # # whiserpx
                result = whisper_model.transcribe(speech_audio)
                print("Transcription: ", result)

                # reset buffer
                speech_buffer = []

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Terminating...")

finally:
    # Close the stream gracefully
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

When I run this, I get these errors:
ReproducibilityWarning: TensorFloat-32 (TF32) has been disabled as it might lead to reproducibility issues and lower accuracy.       
It can be re-enabled by calling
   >>> import torch
   >>> torch.backends.cuda.matmul.allow_tf32 = True
   >>> torch.backends.cudnn.allow_tf32 = True
See https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio/issues/1370 for more details.

  warnings.warn(
Could not locate cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll. Please make sure it is in your library path!

This error only occurs when I'm trying to pass in numpy array to whisperx. If I pass in a wav file, transcription works.
I would like to know if my logic is correct, or if I am missing something.
Also, how do I fix my code to make transcription work?
Thank you.
